# Css code how to create multiple div classes

Tags: html, css

In my css I have the following:--

and my html code is

```
    <div class="contanier">

    <div id="rightcol">Right Section</div>
<div id="content">Content Section</div>

    </div>
```

But I am getting the page which is not appearing in the middle..To achieve this,what I have to do??

Comment: That's a lot of irrelevant CSS you have there; next time please try to trim that down to the absolute minimum required to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add in display:block in place of display:inline-block

.contanier
{
display:block;
}
```

Comment: Indeed (or just leave the `display:inline-block` out). Inline-block elements don't handle `margin:auto` the same as block types.

Comment: add display:block in place of it

Comment: Now I am getting "container3" and  "container2" in center..But not getting the "container 2' and "container3" one after another..

Comment: @preeti Your question doesn't mention container2 and container3 at all.

Comment: without coding i can't understand what are you asking for